# XLConnect loadWorkbook error - POIXMLException (Java)

Tags: r, excel, apache-poi, xlconnect

I'm trying to load a hefty Excel workbook (.xlsm format, ~30 mb) that has a large number of array calcs.

```
> wb1 <- loadWorkbook("Mar_SP_20130227_V6.1.xlsm")
Error: POIXMLException (Java): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

But I am able to successfully load a values-only/no-macro version of the workbook.

```
> wb2 <- loadWorkbook("Mar_SP_20130227_V6.1_VALUES_ONLY.xlsx")
> wb2
[1] "Mar_SP_20130227_V6.1_VALUES_ONLY.xlsx"
```

What could be causing the error?

From the maintainer's [website](http://www.mirai-solutions.com/site/index.cfm?id_art=69890&actMenuItemID=31456&plainerr=yes&vsprache=EN) I can see that there can be issues with workbooks containing array calcs or unsupported formula functions, but this doesn't look like the same errror.

Java Info:

```
C:\> java -version
java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.0-b17, mixed mode)
```

Comment: What's the full stacktrace? (There should be a lot more than just that one line)

Comment: Hi Gagravarr, that's all that's exposed to the user (me) by the XLConnect R package (which uses the ApachePOI). Are there logs in the java directory that would show me the stracktrace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that the root of this error was the JVM running out of memory (even with `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1024m")`).

I tried to increase the memory, but couldn't get the JVM to take more than `-Xmx2048m`, which still wasn't enough to load the workbook.

So I upgraded the JRE from 32 bit to 64 bit and ran 64 bit R.

I was then able to set `-Xmx4096m` and successfully load my 30mb workbook.

Comment: Still not working for me. I get "Error: POIXMLException (Java): java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException". My XLSB files are over 100 MB. :-/

Comment: What did you set `-Xmx4096m` to? How much RAM does your computer have?

Comment: I've tried different settings, and my machine has 24 GB of RAM. Processor is a 2 GHz Intel Xeon.